# Assign a struct implementation to another struct implementation

Tags: rust, struct, ownership

I'd like to keep an instance of the handlebars registry in a struct named "Mailer".

The instance is to be initialized upon running the "new" function of the Mailer implementation.

I do have massive problems in figuring out the proper ownership at each scope.

```
use handlebars::Handlebars; 

pub struct Mailer<'reg> {
   registry: &'reg handlebars::Handlebars<'reg>
}

impl <'reg>Mailer<'reg> {
    pub fn new() -> &'reg Mailer<'reg> {
       let registry = handlebars::Handlebars::new();       
       Mailer { registry: &registry }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let mailer = Mailer::new();
    Ok(())
}
```

The compiler presents these errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/utils/mailer.rs:9:8
   |
8  |     pub fn new() -> &'reg Mailer<'reg> {
   |                     ------------------ expected `&'reg Mailer<'reg>` because of return type
...
9  |        Mailer { registry: &registry }
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |        |
   |        expected `&Mailer<'reg>`, found struct `Mailer`
   |        help: consider borrowing here: `&Mailer { registry: &registry }`
```

Basically I don't know how to annotate the returned Mailer Struct properly.

Simply returning

```
&Mailer<'req> { registry: &registry }
```

instead of

```
Mailer { registry: &registry }
```

is not a remedy at all.

I am definitely missing a lot about ownership in the Rust documentation. In my defense, I've not found any example or explanation covering struct implementations assigning other struct implementations.

I am seriously lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new` function returns a `&Mailer<'_>` (with lifetimes hidden), but your final expression is `Mailer { ... }`, which has type `Mailer<'_>`, not `&Mailer<'_>`, so you get an error.

Simply making it return `&Mailer { ... }` doesn't work for a different reason.

Let's imagine writing it like this, which is equivalent:

```rust
fn new() -> &'reg Mailer<'reg> {
  let registry = handlebars::Handlebars::new();       
  let mailer = Mailer { registry: &registry };
  return &mailer;
}
```

In Rust, the only way to pass ownership of some data from a function to its caller is by returning it. For example, if I create a `Vec` in a function, and I want to pass ownership to the caller, I must return it:

```rust
fn make_vec() -> Vec<i32> {
  vec![1, 2, 3]
}
```

The calling code takes ownership of the vec, and is therefore responsible for dropping it.

Going back to your code, you're creating a `Mailer`, but you're not returning it to the caller, you're only returning a reference to it. Ownership stays inside `new`, and so `new` is responsible for dropping it.

When the function returns, `mailer` is then dropped, since it's reached the end of the scope it was declared in, but we've kept a reference to it (by returning it to the caller). This isn't allowed, since it would allow use-after-free (using a reference to some data after that data has been dropped).

I haven't worked with handlebars in Rust before, but you probably want to change your code to look like this:

```rust
struct Mailer<'reg> {
  registry: handlebars::Handlebars<'reg>  // no reference here
}

impl<'reg> Mailer<'reg> {
  fn new() -> Self {
    let registry = handlebars::Handlebars::new();
    Self { registry }  // shorthand for Self { registry: registry }
  }
}
```

The key differences are:

- `Mailer` takes an **owned** `Handlebars` instance, rather than a reference to one
- `new` returns an **owned** `Mailer`

This way, full ownership is passed to the caller of `Mailer::new`

Comment: Thanks, you're answer and explanation are pure gold. For some stupid reason I thought I had to "juggle" around references. Now it all makes sense. I'm really grateful for your reply!

Comment: No problem :) It's important to remember the distinction between *a type which has a lifetime* (like `Handlebars<'reg>) and a reference with a lifetime (like `&'a i32`). `Handlebars<'reg>` likely *contains* a reference, but it is not a reference itself. It's definitely a confusing topic